# Merge two rows from a table in a single row

Tags: postgresql, join

I think it's pretty simple but I can't get around this one…
I have a table `contactsFields` like this :

```
| id | contactId | fieldType | order | value |
```

I want to get the `email` with `order` 0 and `company` with `order` 0 as well.

Pretty straightforward to get either one :

```
SELECT "contactId", "value"
FROM "contactFields"
WHERE "order" = 0 AND "fieldType" = '<email OR company>';
```

This query can return no row, or a single one because we enforce that there are never 2 fields with same `fieldType`, `contactId` and `order`

But I would like to get both of them at the same time (i.e. merge 2 results on a single row), like this:

```
| contactId | emailWithOrder0 | companyWithOrder0 |
```

Can I do this with a join?

Comment: It is not clear what the sentences "This query can return no row, or a single one... But I would like to get both of them" mean. Can you add some sample data and expected result

Comment: Sorry about that. The answer below works perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

@a_horse_with-no_name's query improved:

```
SELECT "contactId", 
        email, 
        company
FROM 
    ( SELECT "contactId", "value" AS email
      FROM "contactFields"
      WHERE "fieldType" = 'email'
        AND "order" = 0
    ) AS e
  FULL JOIN 
    ( SELECT "contactId", "value" AS company
      FROM "contactFields"
      WHERE "fieldType" = 'company'
        AND "order" = 0
    ) AS c 
  USING ("contactId") ;
```